# scanf and printf not printing right values

Tags: c, string, printf, scanf, stdio

What is going on here?
The code goes like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char name[15];
    char name_[15];
    char answ[1];

    printf("What's your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", name);

    strcpy(name_, name);

    printf("Yes / No: ");
    scanf("%s", answ);

    printf("Hello! %s\n", name_);
    printf("You said: %s\n", answ);

    return 0;
}
```

With input "name" and "yes" the expected output is that it says:

> Hello! name
>
> You said: yes

Instead I get:

> Hello! es
>
> You said: yes

I also tried adding spaces before %s with no results.

So what exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you bother with `name` and `name_`? Just use `name`.

Comment: You need to allocate more space for `answ`. Right now, it can only store an empty string.

Comment: `char answ[1];` is One-Character-Too-Few to hold `"y"` or `"n"` (which are actually `"y\0"` or `"n\0"` (you forgot space for the *nul-terminating* character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`answ` can contain only 1 character. So currently, the extra character `"es"` +  `'\0'` gets written into the memory assigned to `name_`.
So, `"es"` gets printed.

Answer (score 1):

You've only allocated space for a one-character yes/no answer, but are writing more characters into it.

This results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate more space for `answ`, not forgetting about the NUL terminator.

Comment: oh welp I overlooked that part

Comment: Improvement: Consider using strncpy instead

Answer (score 1):

You have created a classic exploitable buffer overrun but in your code. This is why most modern compilers would advise you to swap sscanf to sscanf_s or similar. As other people have pointed out, you overwrite the next variable on the stack.

I wanted to provide this answer to basically say: never ever use sscanf or any of the obsolete, insecure C functions. Even if this is probably just a toy example, get the practice in to write modern C code. You’ll benefit from this in the long run.